# Running java program through command-line jdb executes correctly but fails when executed as java command-line

Tags: java, jdb

I am relatively unexperienced in java, so hopefully I will be able to provide enough information here for this to be relevant and useful for other people.

I am trying to run someone else's codebase that takes two input files, prints some information to STDOUT while running the code through them and quits.

I compiled the code with a command like the one below:

```
java -g -cp .:../../deps/dep1.jar:../../deps/dep2.jar:../../deps/dep3.jar nameofclass/Nameofclass.java nameofclass/File1.java nameofclass/File2.java nameofclass/File3.java
```

I can then execute with `jdb` as shown below:

```
jdb -classpath ".:../../deps/dep1.jar:../../deps/dep2.jar:../../deps/dep3.jar:" nameofclass.Nameofclass file1.ext file2.ext
```

Then in jdb:

```
run nameofclass.Nameofclass file1.ext file2.ext
```

When I do so, in jdb I get the print out of the process that correctly runs the code, and finishes with a `The application exited`:

```
Set uncaught java.langh.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.langh.Throwable
>
VM Started: /path/to/src

<print out of the code running correctly>

The application exited
```

So far, so good. When I try to run the same code with `java` instead of `jdb`, I get:

```
java -cp ".:../../deps/dep1.jar:../../deps/dep2.jar:../../deps/dep3.jar:" nameofclass.Nameofclass file1.ext file2.ext

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
```

with the trace pointing to a line of code at the very beginning of the main function, which does not seem to have any issues running with `jdb`.

Any ideas how to run the code that I can run successfully with `jdb` but simply with `java` on the command-line here?

Comment: StringConcatFactory is since Java 9. Maybe check the java version (java -version).

Comment: what is the java -version?

Comment: Ah! I see. I think I had a borked installation of openjdk-9 for `jdb` and an older java for `java`. I have now corrected following: https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the StringFactory error was pointing the fact that my Java installation was borked in my Ubuntu 16.04, with `jdb` running Java 9 but `java` pointing to a `/usr/bin/java` version much older than that. I corrected the issue with:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in

and finally running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

After doing that, running `java` similarly to `jdb` worked.